# SQL Korma "count not supported on this type" error message

Tags: sqlkorma

Doing a very simple request rows from 1 table i.e. select * from users.
I am trying to pass the response to a selmer template to iterate over but i get the error message above and indeed i cant do the following

```
(count get-users)
```

so it looks like the response is not a Seq

so how do i convert the output of the below to a seq

```
(defn get-users []
  (select users ))
```

and so use in the below selmer call

```
(defn home-page []  
   (layout/render
    "users.html" {:users gw/get-users} ))
```

I am using 0.4.0 of korma

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im an idiot. 
Should be

```
{:users (gw/get-users)}
```

What a newb